# Logic for letter patterns when searching for words

Tags: c++, templates, encryption

As part of a project, I have to use a templated Map data structure to decode messages. To do so, I have to find common letter patterns in each word in a list of words. Suppose we use ABCDEFGH.. as the source of our labels, so that "indeed" and "grotto" have the pattern ABCDDC. Consider the ciphertext word "xyqbbq". It has the pattern ABCDDC!

How do I begin going about doing this? Creating a Map between each word and its corresponding letter pattern seems like the logical thing to do, but how would I return for a list of words with the same letter pattern efficiently? I can't create a Map, say from a string to a vector of strings- this is because the Map class that I defined cannot use the STL as its template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an array with 26 char entries, one for each letter you can have in a word. Start by initialise each entry to '-'

Then when you run through your word, you will look up each letter in this array. If the corresponding entry is a '-', you will replace the letter in the array with the next available substitution letter, if not you can just use the one thats in the array.

```
With grotto / ABCDDC you would have the following in the array:

           a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
Array[26]: - - - - - - A - - - - - - - C - - B - D - - - - - -
```